# How to structure data in order to use recommendation engine in mahout

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine

For instance, i have a transaction table that tracking which user had buy which item and the quantity. My data only include user, item and quantity. Therefore, how can i use mahout to recommend other items to the user ?
Any recommendation method will do....

For example, the transaction table data:

```
User   Item    Quantity

user1  item1         20
user1  item2         50 
user1  item3          0
user1  item4         10
user1  item5          0

user2  item1         50
user2  item2          1
user2  item3        100
user2  item4         77
user2  item5         40

user3  item1        150
user3  item2          0
user3  item3          5
user3  item4         10
user3  item5         40
```

How can i know which item should i recommend to user1 ?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more information?

Answer (score 0):

I think using quantity column is not so sensible in a recommendation system. At least mahout does not have implementation for quantity of data (instead, implementation for ratings exists).

So you can remove quantity column and rows with 0 quantity then you will have boolean pref dataset.

There are several implementation methods for boolean pref datasets such as;

http://bigdatahandling.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/recommendations-with-mahout-for-boolean.html